# Create functions in Maya optionMenuGrp

Tags: python, maya

Is it possible to pass functions into Maya optionMenuGrp (combobox-alike)?

I have done up a simple UI where I have this combobox (maya cmds not PyQt) and there are 2 options in it.

I tried out using the following code but I was prompted with errors in the menuItem statements:

```
# Error: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
#   File "<maya console>", line 9
# SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg #
```

Then I tried playing around with the placement of test1_func() or test2_func, it print out the statement as the code is executed but not executing it anymore if I tried to select the second menu item...

My code:

```
def __init__(self, transform, startAnimation, endAnimation, cameraObj):

    self.fileExport = []
    self.initialWindow()

    mayaGlobal = OpenMaya.MGlobal()
    mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(1))

    for i in range(startAnimation, (endAnimation + 1)):

        focalLength = cameraObj.focalLength()

        vFilmApp = cameraObj.verticalFilmAperture()

        focalOut = 2* math.degrees(math.atan(vFilmApp * 25.4/ (2* focalLength)))

        myEuler = OpenMaya.MEulerRotation()
        spc = OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld

        trans = transform.getTranslation(spc)

        rotation = transform.getRotation(myEuler)
        rotVector = OpenMaya.MVector(myEuler.asVector())

        self.fileExport.append((str(i) + '\t' + str(trans[0]) + "\t" + str(trans[1]) + "\t" + str(trans[2]) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[0])) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[1])) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[2])) + "\t" + str(focalOut) + "\n"))

        mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(i+1))


def optionMenuCallback(*args):
    fn = cmds.menuItem (args[0], q=True, c=True)
    if fn:
        fn()

def menu1Callback():
    print 'menu 1 fired'
    startAnimation = cmds.playbackOptions(query=True, minTime=True)
    endAnimation = cmds.playbackOptions(query=True, maxTime=True)
    return startAnimation
    return endAnimation

def menu2Callback():
    print 'menu 2 fired'
    startAnimation = cmds.findKeyframe(which='first')
    endAnimation = cmds.findKeyframe(which='last')
    return startAnimation
    return endAnimation

def initialWindow(self, *args):
    w = cmds.window(w=150, h=100, title = "Export Selection" )
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    form = cmds.formLayout(numberOfDivisions=100)
    exportSelection = cmds.optionMenuGrp(label='example', cc=optionMenuCallback)
    test1 = cmds.menuItem('item1', c = menu1Callback)
    test1 = cmds.menuItem('item2', c= menu2Callback)
    cmds.showWindow(w)


def __call__(self):
    return self.fileExport
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook to the changeCommand in the optionMenu itself, not menu item' commands. However, since the optionMenu callback will pass the selected item you can use that to grab the callback from the menu item itself and fire it manually:

```
def optionMenuCallback(*args):
    fn = cmds.menuItem (args[0], q=True, c=True)
    if fn:
        fn()

def menu1Callback():
    cmds.polySphere(n='created_by_item1')
    print 'menu 1 fired'

def menu2Callback():
    cmds.polyCube(n='created_by_item_2')
    print 'menu 2 fired'

w = cmds.window(w=150, h=100)
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
form = cmds.formLayout(numberOfDivisions=100)
exportSelection = cmds.optionMenuGrp(label='example', cc=optionMenuCallback)
test1 = cmds.menuItem('item1', c = menu1Callback)
test1 = cmds.menuItem('item2', c= menu2Callback)
cmds.showWindow(w)
```

Comment: I have a question though, where does the `fn()` comes from? Is it the same `fn` as in the `optionMenuCallback`? Pardon me, but say if ultimately I had wanted to have a button that takes in the values depending on the selection, will it be possible to have it return back into `__init__`? I have edited my post

Comment: `fn` is coming from the line `cmds.menuItem (args[0], q=True, c=True)` which is calling `menuItem` with the -q flag and the -c flag to ask 'what is the callback of this menu item'.  The menu item itself is getting passed in as an argument by the changeCommand.   This arrangement lets you have a different command for each menu item and uses the changeCommand on the optionMenu to fire off the one you have selected